# Spring and JPA. Table not found

Tags: mysql, spring, jpa

I have a MySQL db and I'm tryng to configure a spring app to access to it. I created a new JPA Spring project from template.

I modified the persistence.xml, so now it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
             version="1.0">

    <persistence-unit name="application" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

        <class>com.windy.spring.FavoriteSport</class>
        <class>com.windy.spring.FavoriteSpot</class>
        <class>com.windy.spring.FavoriteUser</class>
        <class>com.windy.spring.Role</class>
        <class>com.windy.spring.Sport</class>
        <class>com.windy.spring.Spot</class>
        <class>com.windy.spring.SpotReview</class>
        <class>com.windy.spring.User</class>
        <class>com.windy.spring.UserAccount</class>

        <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>

    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

When the project is generated a JpaConfiguration Class is also generated:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.hibernate.cache.HashtableCacheProvider;
import org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.Database;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;

@Configuration
public class JpaConfiguration {

    @Value("#{dataSource}")
    private javax.sql.DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> jpaProperties() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        props.put("hibernate.dialect", H2Dialect.class.getName());
        props.put("hibernate.cache.provider_class", HashtableCacheProvider.class.getName());
        return props;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(false);
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.H2);
        return hibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new JpaTransactionManager( localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean().getObject() );
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean lef = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        lef.setDataSource(this.dataSource);
        lef.setJpaPropertyMap(this.jpaProperties());
        lef.setJpaVendorAdapter(this.jpaVendorAdapter());
        return lef;
    }

}
```

Of course I have generetad also the entities. And my app-context.xml is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <description>Example configuration to get you started.</description>

    <jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource" type="H2" />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.windy.spring" />

</beans>
```

I would like to access to my mysql db server and the url of the connection is the following (with user and password)
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mynewdb".
I do not understand where I have to indicate the jdbc parameters to use the connection because I get the following log:

```
2012-01-30 21:14:05,625 INFO [org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager] - <@TestExecutionListeners is not present for class [class com.windy.spring.OrderPersistenceTests]: using defaults.>
2012-01-30 21:14:05,774 INFO [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader] - <Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [com/windy/spring/OrderPersistenceTests-context.xml]>
2012-01-30 21:14:05,930 INFO [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader] - <Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [META-INF/spring/app-context.xml]>
2012-01-30 21:14:06,180 INFO [org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext] - <Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@2d342ba4: startup date [Mon Jan 30 21:14:06 CET 2012]; root of context hierarchy>
2012-01-30 21:14:06,514 INFO [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] - <Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@3d3cdaa: defining beans [dataSource,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,jpaConfiguration,jpaDaoRole,jpaDaoUser,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,jpaProperties,jpaVendorAdapter,transactionManager,localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]; root of factory hierarchy>
2012-01-30 21:14:06,549 INFO [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseFactory] - <Creating embedded database 'dataSource'>
2012-01-30 21:14:06,631 INFO [com.windy.spring.JpaDao] - <class com.windy.spring.Role>
2012-01-30 21:14:06,736 INFO [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean] - <Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'application'>
2012-01-30 21:14:06,857 INFO [org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version] - <Hibernate Commons Annotations 3.2.0.Final>
2012-01-30 21:14:06,865 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] - <Hibernate 3.6.0.Final>
2012-01-30 21:14:06,867 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] - <hibernate.properties not found>
2012-01-30 21:14:06,870 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] - <Bytecode provider name : javassist>
2012-01-30 21:14:06,873 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] - <using JDK 1.4 java.sql.Timestamp handling>
2012-01-30 21:14:06,942 INFO [org.hibernate.ejb.Version] - <Hibernate EntityManager 3.6.0.Final>
2012-01-30 21:14:06,960 INFO [org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration] - <Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: application
    ...]>
2012-01-30 21:14:07,089 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder] - <Binding entity from annotated class: com.windy.spring.FavoriteSport>
2012-01-30 21:14:07,132 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder] - <Bind entity com.windy.spring.FavoriteSport on table favorite_sport>
2012-01-30 21:14:07,190 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder] - <Binding entity from annotated class: com.windy.spring.FavoriteSpot>
2012-01-30 21:14:07,190 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder] - <Bind entity com.windy.spring.FavoriteSpot on table favorite_spot>
2012-01-30 21:14:07,195 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder] - <Binding entity from annotated class: com.windy.spring.FavoriteUser>
2012-01-30 21:14:07,195 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder] - <Bind entity com.windy.spring.FavoriteUser on table favorite_user>
2012-01-30 21:14:07,198 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder] - <Binding entity from annotated class: com.windy.spring.Role>
2012-01-30 21:14:07,198 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder] - <Bind entity com.windy.spring.Role on table Role>
2012-01-30 21:14:07,226 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder] - <Binding entity from annotated class: com.windy.spring.Sport>
2012-01-30 21:14:07,226 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder] - <Bind entity com.windy.spring.Sport on table Sport>
2012-01-30 21:14:07,229 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder] - <Binding entity from annotated class: com.windy.spring.Spot>
2012-01-30 21:14:07,229 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder] - <Bind entity com.windy.spring.Spot on table Spot>
2012-01-30 21:14:07,244 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder] - <Binding entity from annotated class: com.windy.spring.SpotReview>
2012-01-30 21:14:07,244 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder] - <Bind entity com.windy.spring.SpotReview on table spot_review>
2012-01-30 21:14:07,250 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder] - <Binding entity from annotated class: com.windy.spring.User>
2012-01-30 21:14:07,251 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder] - <Bind entity com.windy.spring.User on table User>
2012-01-30 21:14:07,263 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder] - <Binding entity from annotated class: com.windy.spring.UserAccount>
2012-01-30 21:14:07,264 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder] - <Bind entity com.windy.spring.UserAccount on table user_account>
2012-01-30 21:14:07,273 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder] - <Mapping collection: com.windy.spring.Role.users -> User>
2012-01-30 21:14:07,275 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder] - <Mapping collection: com.windy.spring.Sport.favoriteSports -> favorite_sport>
2012-01-30 21:14:07,275 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder] - <Mapping collection: com.windy.spring.Spot.favoriteSpots -> favorite_spot>
2012-01-30 21:14:07,275 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder] - <Mapping collection: com.windy.spring.Spot.spotReviews -> spot_review>
2012-01-30 21:14:07,276 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder] - <Mapping collection: com.windy.spring.User.favoriteSports -> favorite_sport>
2012-01-30 21:14:07,276 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder] - <Mapping collection: com.windy.spring.User.favoriteSpots -> favorite_spot>
2012-01-30 21:14:07,276 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder] - <Mapping collection: com.windy.spring.User.favoriteUsers1 -> favorite_user>
2012-01-30 21:14:07,276 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder] - <Mapping collection: com.windy.spring.User.favoriteUsers2 -> favorite_user>
2012-01-30 21:14:07,277 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder] - <Mapping collection: com.windy.spring.User.spotReviews -> spot_review>
2012-01-30 21:14:07,277 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder] - <Mapping collection: com.windy.spring.User.userAccounts -> user_account>
2012-01-30 21:14:07,279 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration] - <Hibernate Validator not found: ignoring>
2012-01-30 21:14:07,301 INFO [org.hibernate.validator.util.Version] - <Hibernate Validator 4.1.0.Final>
2012-01-30 21:14:07,309 INFO [org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolver] - <Instantiated an instance of org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.>
2012-01-30 21:14:07,384 INFO [org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolver] - <Instantiated an instance of org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.>
2012-01-30 21:14:07,395 INFO [org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolver] - <Instantiated an instance of org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.>
2012-01-30 21:14:07,399 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.search.HibernateSearchEventListenerRegister] - <Unable to find org.hibernate.search.event.FullTextIndexEventListener on the classpath. Hibernate Search is not enabled.>
2012-01-30 21:14:07,404 INFO [org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory] - <Initializing connection provider: org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider>
2012-01-30 21:14:07,408 INFO [org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider] - <Using provided datasource>
2012-01-30 21:14:07,568 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] - <Database ->
       name : H2
    version : 1.3.156 (2011-06-17)
      major : 1
      minor : 3>
2012-01-30 21:14:07,568 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] - <Driver ->
       name : H2 JDBC Driver
    version : 1.3.156 (2011-06-17)
      major : 1
      minor : 3>
2012-01-30 21:14:07,589 INFO [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] - <Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect>
2012-01-30 21:14:07,599 INFO [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.JdbcSupportLoader] - <Disabling contextual LOB creation as JDBC driver reported JDBC version [3] less than 4>
2012-01-30 21:14:07,600 INFO [org.hibernate.transaction.TransactionFactoryFactory] - <Transaction strategy: org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory>
2012-01-30 21:14:07,601 INFO [org.hibernate.transaction.TransactionManagerLookupFactory] - <No TransactionManagerLookup configured (in JTA environment, use of read-write or transactional second-level cache is not recommended)>
2012-01-30 21:14:07,601 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] - <Automatic flush during beforeCompletion(): disabled>
2012-01-30 21:14:07,601 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] - <Automatic session close at end of transaction: disabled>
2012-01-30 21:14:07,601 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] - <JDBC batch size: 15>
2012-01-30 21:14:07,601 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] - <JDBC batch updates for versioned data: disabled>
2012-01-30 21:14:07,602 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] - <Scrollable result sets: enabled>
2012-01-30 21:14:07,602 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] - <JDBC3 getGeneratedKeys(): enabled>
2012-01-30 21:14:07,602 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] - <Connection release mode: auto>
2012-01-30 21:14:07,603 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] - <Default batch fetch size: 1>
2012-01-30 21:14:07,603 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] - <Generate SQL with comments: disabled>
2012-01-30 21:14:07,603 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] - <Order SQL updates by primary key: disabled>
2012-01-30 21:14:07,603 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] - <Order SQL inserts for batching: disabled>
2012-01-30 21:14:07,603 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] - <Query translator: org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory>
2012-01-30 21:14:07,606 INFO [org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory] - <Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory>
2012-01-30 21:14:07,606 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] - <Query language substitutions: {}>
2012-01-30 21:14:07,606 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] - <JPA-QL strict compliance: enabled>
2012-01-30 21:14:07,606 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] - <Second-level cache: enabled>
2012-01-30 21:14:07,606 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] - <Query cache: disabled>
2012-01-30 21:14:07,607 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] - <Cache region factory : org.hibernate.cache.impl.bridge.RegionFactoryCacheProviderBridge>
2012-01-30 21:14:07,612 INFO [org.hibernate.cache.impl.bridge.RegionFactoryCacheProviderBridge] - <Cache provider: org.hibernate.cache.HashtableCacheProvider>
2012-01-30 21:14:07,613 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] - <Optimize cache for minimal puts: disabled>
2012-01-30 21:14:07,613 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] - <Structured second-level cache entries: disabled>
2012-01-30 21:14:07,620 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] - <Statistics: disabled>
2012-01-30 21:14:07,620 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] - <Deleted entity synthetic identifier rollback: disabled>
2012-01-30 21:14:07,620 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] - <Default entity-mode: pojo>
2012-01-30 21:14:07,620 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] - <Named query checking : enabled>
2012-01-30 21:14:07,620 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] - <Check Nullability in Core (should be disabled when Bean Validation is on): disabled>
2012-01-30 21:14:07,640 INFO [org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl] - <building session factory>
2012-01-30 21:14:07,894 INFO [org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryObjectFactory] - <Not binding factory to JNDI, no JNDI name configured>
2012-01-30 21:14:07,900 INFO [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] - <Running hbm2ddl schema update>
2012-01-30 21:14:07,900 INFO [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] - <fetching database metadata>
2012-01-30 21:14:07,930 INFO [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] - <updating schema>
2012-01-30 21:14:07,931 INFO [org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolver] - <Instantiated an instance of org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.>
2012-01-30 21:14:07,950 INFO [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseMetadata] - <table not found: Role>
2012-01-30 21:14:07,951 INFO [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseMetadata] - <table not found: Sport>
2012-01-30 21:14:07,952 INFO [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseMetadata] - <table not found: Spot>
2012-01-30 21:14:07,953 INFO [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseMetadata] - <table not found: User>
2012-01-30 21:14:07,954 INFO [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseMetadata] - <table not found: favorite_sport>
2012-01-30 21:14:07,955 INFO [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseMetadata] - <table not found: favorite_spot>
2012-01-30 21:14:07,956 INFO [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseMetadata] - <table not found: favorite_user>
2012-01-30 21:14:07,957 INFO [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseMetadata] - <table not found: spot_review>
2012-01-30 21:14:07,958 INFO [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseMetadata] - <table not found: user_account>
2012-01-30 21:14:07,959 INFO [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseMetadata] - <table not found: Role>
2012-01-30 21:14:07,960 INFO [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseMetadata] - <table not found: Sport>
2012-01-30 21:14:07,961 INFO [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseMetadata] - <table not found: Spot>
2012-01-30 21:14:07,962 INFO [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseMetadata] - <table not found: User>
2012-01-30 21:14:07,963 INFO [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseMetadata] - <table not found: favorite_sport>
2012-01-30 21:14:07,964 INFO [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseMetadata] - <table not found: favorite_spot>
2012-01-30 21:14:07,966 INFO [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseMetadata] - <table not found: favorite_user>
2012-01-30 21:14:07,967 INFO [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseMetadata] - <table not found: spot_review>
2012-01-30 21:14:07,967 INFO [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseMetadata] - <table not found: user_account>
2012-01-30 21:14:08,053 INFO [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] - <schema update complete>
2012-01-30 21:14:08,124 INFO [com.windy.spring.JpaDao] - <class com.windy.spring.User>
2012-01-30 21:14:08,253 DEBUG [org.hibernate.SQL] - <select role0_.id_role as id1_3_0_, role0_.description as descript2_3_0_ from Role role0_ where role0_.id_role=?>
2012-01-30 21:14:08,262 INFO [org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext] - <Closing org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@2d342ba4: startup date [Mon Jan 30 21:14:06 CET 2012]; root of context hierarchy>
2012-01-30 21:14:08,263 INFO [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] - <Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@3d3cdaa: defining beans [dataSource,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,jpaConfiguration,jpaDaoRole,jpaDaoUser,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,jpaProperties,jpaVendorAdapter,transactionManager,localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]; root of factory hierarchy>
2012-01-30 21:14:08,263 INFO [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean] - <Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'application'>
2012-01-30 21:14:08,263 INFO [org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl] - <closing>
```

Anyone knows how what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for your help

Danilo

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem when generating the code: you don't understand the code that is generated, because you don't read the javadoc and the reference manual. The key here is the DataSource. This is the class which creates JDBC connections. You configured it, in the app-context.xml file to be a datasource for an embedded database of type H2. You want a real pooled datasource, creating connections to the MySQL database. Of course, the dialect and the database type of the JPA vendor adapter must also be changed to MySQL.

See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#jdbc-datasource for how to configure a DataSource in Spring.